# Looking the cause of a race condition on a multicore corepack

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, race-condition, armv7

I am using a simple software queue based on a write index and a read index.

Introduction details; Language: C, Compiler: GCC Optimization: -O3 with extra parameters, Architecture: Armv7a, CPU: Multicore, 2 Cortex A-15, L2 Cache: Shared and enabled, L1 Cache: Every CPU, enabled, Architecture is supposed to be cache coherent.

CPU 1 does the writing stuff and CPU 2 does the reading stuff. Below is the very simplified example code. You can assume the initial values of the indexes are zero.

COMMON:

```
#define QUE_LEN 4

unsigned int my_que_write_index = 0; //memory
unsigned int my_que_read_index = 0; //memory

struct my_que_struct{
  unsigned int param1;
  unsigned int param2;
};

struct my_que_struct my_que[QUE_LEN]; //memory
```

CPU 1 runs:

```
void que_writer
{
unsigned int write_index_local;

write_index_local = my_que_write_index; //my_que_write_index is in memory
my_que[write_index_local].param1 = 16; //my_que is my queue and stored in memory also
my_que[write_index_local].param2 = 32;
//similar writing stuff

++write_index_local;
if(write_index_local == QUE_LEN) write_index_local = 0;

my_que_write_index = write_index_local;
}
```

CPU 2 runs:

```
void que_reader()
{
unsigned int read_index_local, param1, param2;

read_index_local = my_que_read_index; //also in memory
while(read_index_local != my_que_write_index)
 {
   param1 = my_que[read_index_local].param1;

   if(param1 == 0) FATAL_ERROR;

   param2 = my_que[read_index_local].param2;
   //similar reading stuff

   my_que[read_index_local].param1 = 0;

   ++read_index_local;
   if(read_index_local == QUE_LEN) read_index_local = 0;
 }

my_que_read_index = read_index_local;
}
```

Okay, in a normal case, fatal error should never occur because param1 of the queue is always stored with a constant value of 16. But somehow param1 of the queue is happening 0 and fatal error occurs.

It is clear that this is somehow a race condition problem, but I can't figure how it is happening. Indexes are updated seperately by the CPUs.

I don't want to fill my code with memory barriers without understanding the core of the problem. Do you have any idea how this is happening?

Details: This is a baremetal system, these codes are interrupt-disabled, and there is no preemption or task switching.

Comment: Do not post a "simplified version", but a [mcve]. You do not even show the declarations.

Comment: You are aware the compiler will likely reorder the code at will? You will need `stdatomic.h`. There are quite some articles, including code-snippets to implement thread-safe buffers; I strongly recommend you read them carefully first. For instance: why should the read-code actually re-read the write-index, as it is not changed from its point of view?

Comment: Just to be sure, you have enabled the ACTLR SMP bit on both cores, yes? Are they both using the same page table, and what memory type and attributes is that set up for? As for understanding where and why you need barriers (assuming you're not actually using uncached strongly-ordered memory), I'd suggest trying to make sense of [this document](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.genc007826/index.html).

Comment: can you post the de-assemble assembly code of this code from your tool chain, then probably you will come to know what reordering is done by compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler and the CPU are allowed to rearrange stores and loads as they see fit (i.e. as long as a single threaded program would not be able to observe a difference). Of course for multi-threaded programs these effects are observable quite well.

For example, this code

```
write_index_local = my_que_write_index;
my_que[write_index_local].param1 = 16;
my_que[write_index_local].param2 = 32;
++write_index_local;
if(write_index_local == QUE_LEN) write_index_local = 0;
my_que_write_index = write_index_local;
```

could be reordered like this

```
a = my_que_write_index;
my_que_write_index = write_index_local == QUE_LEN - 1 ? 0 : a + 1;
my_que[a].param1 = 16;
my_que[a].param2 = 32;
```

Getting this stuff right requires atomics and barriers that avoid these kinds of reorderings. Check out Preshing's excellent series of blog posts to learn about atomics, this one is probably a good start: http://preshing.com/20120612/an-introduction-to-lock-free-programming/ but check out the following ones as well.